# Using each() for checking which class is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here's my problem, I'm new to jQuery. What I am trying to do here is check for user to click on a certain table cell/row and it would then display a div named popup of an index the same as the table cell *votes*. Without having to make separate functions of all the rows in my table.

Using some numerical value will display all the dialogs from a click of the cell of the same value the first time and from the second time only the correct one.

I bet there's some other way to do it and maybe there's just a stupid error. 
Using the index value in the *click* and *dialog* function won't work.

I am open to suggestions on improvement also.

The scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
       $(document).ready( function() {

          $('.votes').each(function(index) {
              $('.votes:eq(index)').click(function() {

                  $('.popup:eq(index)').dialog();

              });
          });

        });
    </script>
```

HTML for the table part, only a snippet

```
<td class='votes'>5</td>
<td class='votes'>15</td>
<td class='votes'>25</td>
```

HTML for the div part, only a snippet of the div:

```
<div class='popup'>
    <ul>
        <li>John Johnsson</li>
        <li>John Doe</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class='popup'>
    <ul>
        <li>Matt Theman</li>
        <li>Peter Watley</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, the main problem is that you are not using string concatenation to apply the index to the selector ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ChvX/)):

```
$('.votes:eq(index)')
// the Sizzle selector engine doesn't know what the string "index" is.
```

instead of

```
$('.votes:eq(' + index + ')')
// using concatenation calls the .toString() method of index to apply "0" (or "1", "2", etc.)
// so that the parsed string becomes '.votes:eq(0)' which the Sizzle selector engine understands
```

Once the Sizzle selector engine understands which elements to target ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ChvX/1/)), the second problem is how jQueryUI changes the DOM with the `.dialog` method.

Inital markup:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="votes">5</td>
            <td class="votes">15</td>
            <td class="votes">25</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="popup">
    <ul>
        <li>John Johnsson</li>
        <li>John Doe</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="popup">
    <ul>
        <li>Matt Theman</li>
        <li>Peter Watley</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Once the first click event is handled, one of the `div.popup` elements is transformed into a jQueryUI Dialog and is *appended* to the body, removing it from its initial position, like so:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="votes">5</td>
            <td class="votes">15</td>
            <td class="votes">25</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="popup">
    <ul>
        <li>Matt Theman</li>
        <li>Peter Watley</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ..."> ... </div>
```

So your initial indexes no longer apply. Fortunately, there are several solutions to both problems (a few of which I've listed below).

**Solutions to Problem 1:**

1. Use string concatenation as described above.
2. Use the `.eq` method instead, which will accept the `index` variable as-is
3. Use a delegate handler instead and grab the index from within the handler:

Example of 2:

```
$('.votes').eq(index);
```

Example of 3:

```
$('table').on('click', '.votes', function (e) {
    var vote = $(this),
        index = vote.parent().index(vote);
});
```

**Solutions to Problem 2:**

1. Create all of the dialogs initially and open them as needed.
2. Create the dialogs using a deep clone of the `div` element. (Not recommended)
3. Remove the `td` element to match the removed and re-appended `div` element. (Not recommended)

Example of 1:

```
var popups = [];
$('.popup').each(function (i, elem) {
    var popup = $(elem).data('index', i).dialog({
        "autoOpen": false
    });
    popups.push(popup)
});
$('table').on('click', '.votes', function (e) {
    var vote = $(this),
        index = vote.index();
    popups[index].dialog('open');
});
```

I'm sure there are other solutions as well, but these are the ones I thought of of the top of my head.

**[Functional demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2ChvX/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/2ChvX/2/)**

**UPDATE**:

With your chosen table structure, you're actually looking for the index of the parent `tr` element as that is what corresponds with the `div.popup` element. To get the index of the parent `tr` element, change the line that gets the index from:

```
index = vote.index();
```

to:

```
index = vote.parent().index();
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AZpUQ/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, however as my table is a bit different could you point out where i'm messing up ? The error is the same as on my webpage, I get an index of 4 always. I know it's the difference in the table layout: http://jsfiddle.net/AZpUQ/

Comment: That's a lot of work you put into this answer, with excellent explanations. You deserve to win the question for that alone. I hope the OP will bookmark this question and re-read in future. **+1**

Comment: @pete Thanks alot this is what I was after the whole time without knowing it :) And thank you again for such a thorough explanation!

Answer (score 3):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/EPYCH/)***

You don't have to iterate using `each` for `.click`, that will happen internally. You can use `.index()` to get the index of the element clicked with reference to its parent.

```
$('.votes').click(function() {
 $('.popup').eq($(this).index()).dialog();
});
```

Comment: Can't really say what this does but it keeps giving me the the 4th div and up no matter what I click on even the same div.

Comment: @user3194551 - The index metric you decide to use is going to dictate which popup shows with relation to the index that the table cell is to the table row. Please see my demo to get a better feel for the relation.

Answer (score 1):

Updated

FWIW, here's an example using the jQueryUI dialog (which I presume you are using?) and javascript sectionRowIndex and cellIndex.

Reusable code allowing you to identify the cell the user clicked in and perform appropriate action.

<kbd>**http://jsfiddle.net/KbgcL/1/**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Label:</th>
        <th>Washington</th>
        <th>Idaho</th>
        <th>California</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='label'>Votes</td>
        <td class='votes'>5</td>
        <td class='votes'>15</td>
        <td class='votes'>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='label'>Voters</td>
        <td class='voters'>5,000</td>
        <td class='voters'>15,000</td>
        <td class='voters'>25,000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
var myTr;

$('#msg').dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    title: 'Report:'
});

$('#myTable tr td').click(function() {
    myTr = $(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex;
    myCell = this.cellIndex;
    myState = $('#myTable').find('tr:eq(0)').find('th:eq(' +myCell+ ')').html();
    myVoters = $('#myTable').find('tr:eq(' +myTr+ ')').find('td:eq(' +myCell+ ')').html();
    if (myTr==2 && myCell==3){
        //California
        $('#msg').html('There are ' +myVoters+ ' voters in ' +myState);
        $('#msg').dialog('open');
    }else if(myTr==1 && myCell==1){
        $('#msg').html('There were ' +myVoters+ ' votes made in ' +myState);
        $('#msg').dialog('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yea I use jQuery Ui dialog. I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. The only drawback here is that I need alot of if-statements. I modified your example for my use, I might go with something else though.